# Center text in a container (EaselJS)

Tags: javascript, canvas, easeljs, createjs

I am new to EaselJS and I am trying to create a colored container with a centered text. This is my code:

```
var width = 100, height = 100;
canvas.width = width + 10;
canvas.height = height + 10;
var container = new c.Container();
container.x = 10;
container.y = 10;
container.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);

var rect = new c.Shape();
rect.graphics.beginFill('#6e7e8e').drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
container.addChild(rect);

var text = new c.Text();
text.set({
    text: 'hello',
    textAlign: 'center'
});
container.addChild(text);
stage.addChild(container);
stage.update();
```

For some reason the text doesn't centered in the container, but half of the text is out of the container. What is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your text is horizontally centered around the x-position it was added (in your case x=0), that's why it is out of the container by half. If you want to center your text in your container, you'll have to define the position yourself :

```
text.set({
    text: 'hello',
});
var b = text.getBounds();
text.x = (width/2) - (b.width/2); 
text.y = (height/2) - (b.height/2);
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want text.x = (width / 2) - (b.width / 2) ?

Comment: @Mister D., how to update the hit area of the text in case of "center" and "right" alignment text?